# Is it possible to (how) to lock a domain server behind a password?

Tags: django, authentication, web-applications, data-protection, domainservices

I've been working on a django Web app to manage some data for tenants. Things like their personal contact information, government ID, tenancy agreements etc (in other words, very gdpr sensitive info) as well as personally private information such as expense reports. All of this is displayed on the front end of the app as intended seeing as it's supposed to be a private tool for internal company use.

At the moment I run it at home on a local machine server so there is little risk involved however for my convenience I'd like to take the Web app live so I can access it while I'm out and about. The issue I'm having is that there really is no reason for anyone other than myself or business associates to use this app and therefore no reason for anyone else to connect to the domain.

I've considered making the landing page of the website a login page and locking all other views behind this with CSRF protection but even that is too close for comfort in my opinion as it would mean allowing external entities tor connect to the app. I'd much rather have a server which refuses any connection to the outside world straight away unless it is from me. In other words, a server which does not divulge any part of the app or database until login credentials have been correctly entered.

What I envision is that once you type in the domain and hit enter, the moment a connection is made, the server prompts you with an alert box asking for login credentials before any of the app or templates are loaded.

Is this even possible? I've never hosted any of my software online and do not want to fall into a nasty data breach situation by taking this live. At the same time it isn't ideal that the current system operates on the premise that I'm home all the time.

Comment: This is a too broad questions for SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Though this can be done by simply using an index page as you said with a login form and if the user is not logged in the session won't load the rest of the pages.

Comment: Thanks Kostas, my mistake regarding the broadness question, I'll try to avoid this in future. Is there any inherent risk in exposing the index page of the app? I know of django-lockdown which essentially does as you've described by requiring a password before the session is allowed to load into any of the other views. However, I still wonder about the potential for a hacker to somehow access files on the server through some kind of future django exploit. Ideally the server shouldn't even respond to anyone other than myself and this appears to be a topic which is not discussed frequently online

Comment: Risk can be found anywhere there is internet! Even your home pc if it is connected has a risk of exploit. The reduction of risk depends on the development process. The possibility the server replies only to you can be done only if it responds to a certain IP that though needs you to have a static IP on the client side.

Comment: I think what you might be looking for is HTTP authentication.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication Although I have no idea how this is done in Django.